# Java multi thread

Tags: java, multithreading, simd

I have a need to perform a single calculation (sum and product) on a large amount of data in java environment. I know that the best solution would be to use SIMD architectures such as CUDA but I do not have the ability to have dedicated hardware.
You know frameworks for map reduce that run on single machine and exploit the multi-core ?

Comment: If there is only one processor then multi-threading will not help for computation intensive application.

Comment: I have a single cpu with 4 core. How can I take advantage of the multi cores architectures ?

Comment: have look at this [tutorial](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html) may help you out

Answer (score 2):

The fork- join framework is often recommended for these kinds of tasks since it automatically uses as many threads as there are cores, you can read more about it in the Java tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html

On the other hand, if you are just summing and multiplying numbers it may be simpler to choose a fixed number of threads, like 4, and have the first thread sum the numbers at  indexes 0,4,8,.. the second at indexes 1,5,9,... the third at 2,6,10,.. and so on

Comment: Thanks,Do you kwnow a framework based on mapreduce for multi thread ?

Comment: Note - depending on the size of each element, interleaving the indexes across threads may introduce a false-sharing problem.  It's usually better to split up the data into [no of cores] contiguous chunks, eg maxIndex/[no of cores.] size each, (or thereabouts - last chunk may be slightly larger).

Comment: Can false sharing occur when all access is read only?

Comment: @Joni - don't think so, no.  The OP did not describe the data struct in any detail, so it may, or may not, be an issue :)